# Correct use of arguments pattern in pgfkeys/append after command in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pgfkeys

I could not find many examples for the correct use of arguments patterns in pgfkes, but I was able to come up with the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{dimen/.style={<->,>=latex,thin,
  every rectangle node/.style={fill=white,midway}
}}

\tikzset{measuring south/.style args={from #1 to #2 is #3}{
        append after command={
            draw (#1.south west) -- ++(0,-1.0) 
            coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,-10pt)
            (#2.south east) -- ++(0,-1.0) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,-10pt)
            [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {#3}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(a)  [draw,rectangle,text=teal] at (0,0) {here};
    \node(b)  [draw,rectangle,text=olive] at (3,0) {there};
    \path[measuring south=from here to there is far,fill=red];

  \node(x) [draw,rectangle,text=blue] at (0,-2) {Heaven};
  \node(y) [draw,rectangle,text=red] at (3,-2) {Hell};
  \draw (x.south west) -- ++(0,-1.0) 
            coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,-10pt)
            (y.south east) -- ++(0,-1.0) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,-10pt)
            [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {sin};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In my output, I would have liked to see the dimension lines from "here" to "there", but these are not visible.

[image: Above: what I currently have; below: what I would like to achieve]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the TikZ/PGF manual (emphasis added):

> **Some** of the path commands described in the following sections take optional arguments. For these
>   commands, when you use this key inside these options, the path will be inserted after the path
>   command is done.

The key here is the "some".  The `append after command` needs a command to be appended after.  Things that work are `node`, `edge`, `to`, and likewise.  Your `\path` has no commands and so there is no chance of the `append after command` being executed.  What you want here is the `insert path` key which sticks in the path at that point.  Once you change that, then you get some output but you also find a few other (small) errors: you didn't name the nodes `here` and `there`, the `fill=red` command is a little odd, and the `draw` needs to be in brackets to be interpreted as a style.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154155/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{dimen/.style={<->,>=latex,thin,
  every rectangle node/.style={fill=white,midway}
}}

\tikzset{measuring south/.style args={from #1 to #2 is #3}{
    insert path={
      [draw] (#1.south west) -- ++(0,-1.0) 
            coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,-10pt)
            (#2.south east) -- ++(0,-1.0) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,-10pt)
            [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {#3}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(a)  [draw,rectangle,text=teal] at (0,0) (here) {here};
    \node(b)  [draw,rectangle,text=olive] at (3,0) (there) {there};
    \path[measuring south=from here to there is far];

  \node(x) [draw,rectangle,text=blue] at (0,-2) {Heaven};
  \node(y) [draw,rectangle,text=red] at (3,-2) {Hell};
  \draw (x.south west) -- ++(0,-1.0) 
            coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,-10pt)
            (y.south east) -- ++(0,-1.0) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,-10pt)
            [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {sin};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: From here to there]

Comment: You were definitely faster than me ;)

Comment: But I missed the fact that the node names were `a` and `b`!  Ooops!

Comment: I was so frustrated with the fact that the code refused to work, that I threw in wrong node names, and lots of garbage, including color and the such. Thanks to both of you guys.

Comment: @YossiGil: for colors within `insert path` you can have a look to my solution, which differs from Andrew's one exactly in that point.

Answer (score 7):

The MWE example presented contains some conceptual errors.

The most relevant one, I think, is that you wish to reference nodes through their text and not through their name. That's what I read in:

```
\node(a)  [draw,rectangle,text=teal] at (0,0) {here};
\node(b)  [draw,rectangle,text=olive] at (3,0) {there};
\path[measuring south=from here to there is far,fill=red];
```

The `\path` syntax should contain `a` and `b`, not `here` and `there`.

Second, here the late options are used in the wrong manner: once the path is ended, that's it, you can't append stuff anymore. So, in `measuring south` you are willing to `insert path` rather than `append after command`. Moreover, since you are changing path options from the main path to the inserted ones, you may want to use `\pgfextra`.

This would have been my way to go:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{dimen/.style={<->,>=latex,thin,
  every rectangle node/.style={fill=white,midway}
}}

\tikzset{measuring south/.style args={from #1 to #2 is #3}{
        insert path={
          \pgfextra{
                \draw[red] (#1.south west) -- ++(0,-1.0)
                coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,-10pt);
                \draw[blue](#2.south east) -- ++(0,-1.0) 
                coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,-10pt);
                \draw[dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node[midway,fill=white] {#3};
          }      
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(a)  [draw,rectangle,text=teal] at (0,0) {here};
    \node(b)  [draw,rectangle,text=olive] at (3,0) {there};
    \path[measuring south=from a to b is far];

  \node(x) [draw,rectangle,text=blue] at (0,-2) {Heaven};
  \node(y) [draw,rectangle,text=red] at (3,-2) {Hell};
  \draw (x.south west) -- ++(0,-1.0) 
            coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,-10pt)
            (y.south east) -- ++(0,-1.0) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,-10pt)
            [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {sin};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]